# How to have google map auto reads from inputs

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am building a site(something like yellow pages) which user will first choose from a pulldown menu on their country > states > city. Then they will be prompt to mark their own location on google map(or drag the market to an accurate location).
How can I send the city chosen from the pulldown menu into the map, so it display a zoom in of the city instead of a worldwide map.

Can i do it without the longitude and lattitude within the database of the pulldown menu?

Answer (score 1):

You will have to make a geocoding request to google maps api and get the corodinates for the address in the drop down and then use the result to zoom the map on that address.

Read about geocoding in the [google maps documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding). You will find examples of usage and anything you need there.

And to get the value of the drop downs and pass it to the js for making a request to google maps, you will need [this function](http://www.tizag.com/javascriptT/javascript-getelementbyid.php).